# Matlab: Get values from the command window

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a script that contains the following function:

```
function x = getx()
    a = 1;
    b = 2 ;
    c = a * b;
    x = c;
end
```

The execution of this code returns the value 'ans', which in this case is x (i.e. 2). However, I would like to see the values of a, b and c. I used to be able to enter these into the command window like this:

```
>> a % I would press enter and then see the following:
   a
     =
       1
>>
```

Can anyone please explain how this can be achieved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Used to when? Was there a version where this worked, and after a new upgrade this behavior is no longer present?

Comment: @woahdae LOL! I think she once had those variables in the base workspace and didn't realize that they had gotten there by some other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the outputs you want to the function definition: `function [a,b,c,x]=getx()`

Then when you call the function from the command line: `[a,b,c,x]=getx()` and you will be able to access those variables.

See [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/function.html) for more details.

Comment: You are a better man than I. +1 for not descending into the peanut gallery.